# Как плейбуком сгенерировать цепочку SSL сертификатов?

Tags: apache2, ansible, openssl

Есть задача - сгенерировать цепочку самоподписанных сертификатов. Я не особо часто сталкивался с подобным, поэтому поймал небольшой клин. Сертификаты в дальнейшем будут использоваться для https вместе с apache2 и nginx. Если я всё правильно помню, то я должен

1. Сгенерировать приватный ключ для подписи запроса сертификатов
2. Сгенерировать запрос корневого сертификата
3. Сгенерировать корневой сертификат
4. Сгенерировать запрос на сертификат хоста
5. Сгенерировать сертификат хоста
6. На клиентских машинах подложить корневой сертификат в доверенные

Родил вот такую роль (tasks/main.yaml):

```
---
  - name: Установка переменных
    set_fact:
      f_private_key_pem_file: "{{ ca_certificates_self_signed_folder }}/{{ primary_domain }}.private_key.pem"
      f_public_key_pem_file: "{{ ca_certificates_self_signed_folder }}/{{ primary_domain }}.private_key.pem"
      f_root_csr_file: "{{ ca_certificates_self_signed_folder }}/root.{{ primary_domain }}.csr"
      f_root_crt_file: "{{ ca_certificates_self_signed_folder }}/root.{{ primary_domain }}.crt"
      f_root_pfx_file: "{{ ca_certificates_self_signed_folder }}/root.{{ primary_domain }}.pfx"
      f_hostname_csr_file: "{{ ca_certificates_self_signed_folder }}/{{ certificate.hostname }}.{{ primary_domain }}.csr"
      f_hostname_crt_file: "{{ ca_certificates_self_signed_folder }}/{{ certificate.hostname }}.{{ primary_domain }}.crt"
      f_hostname_pfx_file: "{{ ca_certificates_self_signed_folder }}/{{ certificate.hostname }}.{{ primary_domain }}.pfx"

  - name: Создание каталога для сертификатов
    file:
      dest: "{{ ca_certificates_self_signed_folder }}"
      state: directory

  - name: Генерация приватного ключа для подписи запроса сертификата
    openssl_privatekey:
      path: "{{ f_private_key_pem_file }}"
      size: 4096
      # passphrase: "{{ ca_certificate_passphrase }}"

  - name: Генерация запроса сертификата, подписанного приватным ключем
    openssl_csr:
      path: "{{ f_root_csr_file }}"
      privatekey_path: "{{ f_private_key_pem_file }}"
      # privatekey_passphrase: "{{ ca_certificate_passphrase }}"
      common_name: "{{ primary_domain }}"
      organization_name: "{{ certificate.organization | default(default_org) }}"

  - name: Генерация корневого сертификата по запросу
    openssl_certificate:
      path: "{{ f_root_crt_file }}"
      privatekey_path: "{{ f_private_key_pem_file }}"
      # privatekey_passphrase: "{{ ca_certificate_passphrase }}"
      csr_path: "{{ f_root_csr_file }}"
      provider: selfsigned
      selfsigned_not_after: "+{{ 365 * 16 }}d"

  - name: Конверт подписанного корневого сертификата в PKCS12 формат с приаттаченым приватным ключем
    openssl_pkcs12:
      action: export
      path: "{{ f_root_pfx_file }}"
      name: "{{ primary_domain }}"
      privatekey_path: "{{ f_private_key_pem_file }}"
      # privatekey_passphrase: "{{ ca_certificate_passphrase }}"
      certificate_path: "{{ f_root_crt_file }}"
      state: present

  - name: Генерация запроса сертификата хоста
    openssl_csr:
      path: "{{ f_hostname_csr_file }}"
      privatekey_path: "{{ f_private_key_pem_file }}"
      # privatekey_passphrase: "{{ ca_certificate_passphrase }}"
      common_name: "{{ certificate.hostname }}.{{ primary_domain }}"
      organization_name: "{{ certificate.organization | default(default_org) }}"

  - name: Генерация сертификата, подписанного корневым сертификатом
    openssl_certificate:
      path: "{{ f_hostname_crt_file }}"
      csr_path: "{{ f_hostname_csr_file }}"
      ownca_path: "{{ f_root_crt_file }}"
      ownca_privatekey_path: "{{ f_private_key_pem_file }}"
      # ownca_privatekey_passphrase: "{{ ca_certificate_passphrase }}"
      provider: ownca

  - name: Конверт сертификата хоста в PKCS12 формат с приаттаченым приватным ключем
    openssl_pkcs12:
      action: export
      path: "{{ f_hostname_pfx_file }}"
      name: "{{ primary_domain }}"
      privatekey_path: "{{ f_private_key_pem_file }}"
      # privatekey_passphrase: "{{ ca_certificate_passphrase }}"
      certificate_path: "{{ f_hostname_crt_file }}"
      state: present

  - name: Установка сертификатов
    copy:
      src: "{{ item }}"
      dest: "{{ ca_certificates_folder }}"
      owner: root
      group: root
      mode: '0644'
      remote_src: yes
    loop:
    - "{{ f_root_pfx_file }}"
    - "{{ f_hostname_crt_file }}"
    notify:
    - update certificates
```

В apache2 приежжают следующие настройки:

```
SSLCertificateFile {{ f_hostname_crt_file }}
SSLCertificateKeyFile {{ f_private_key_pem_file }}
```

Собственно, вопросы

1. При установке корневого pfx сертификата в доверенные в windows не срабатывает доверие, браузеры всё равно предупреждают.
2. В linux нужно в ca-certificates только корневой укладывать?
3. Нужно ли генерировать корневой и хост pem сертификаты и как?